# Angular.js ng-repeat iterate through remote JSON array issue

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

After searching, I cannot see what I am doing incorrectly. Basically my JSON returns an array of data that looks like:

```
  "Alerts": [
    {
      "id": "164579",
      "date": "2013-05-17T16:46:58",
      "type": "ClaimReceivedNotification",
      "descr": "Your claim submission has been received and is pending review by our claims department.",
      "isRead": false,
      "denialId": "",
      "denialType": "",
      "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "amount": 0
    },
.......and so on......
```

So what I am trying to do is lay that out with just the date and the description (descr) as shown in this html:

```
                    <div>
                        <span ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts"> {{ ppt.Alerts[0].date }} </span>
                        <!-- <span> {{ ppt.Alerts[0].descr }} </span> -->
                    </div>
```

It does display, but just the first entry in the array. If I take out the index " [0] " and try to replace as:

```
<span ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts[]"> {{ ppt.Alerts.date }} </span>
```

It displays nothing. Where am I going wrong in using this to get it to iterate through each instance in the array and return particular values?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

As you are repeating `ppt.Alerts` and you already said each element of loop will known as `date`, you could easily use that `date` to show the date of each alert.

**Markup**

```
<span ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts"> {{date.date}} </span>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `date.date` to show only date not to complete object ?

Comment: @Vineet That's my bad..updated answer..Thanks bro.. :)

Comment: Cool, that worked. So why was it "date.date" versus just "date"?

Comment: Oh, and so now, since I return it as a span, it list them over and over, but want it to display date and descr in the span or <p>. So how would I add 2 in there like "ng-repeat="date && descr in ppt.Alerts"? Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Mark that would be very simple..I think you wanted to show descr as well with the date..Then it would be simply `<p ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts"> <span>Date: {{date.date}}<span><span>Descr: {{date.descr}}<span></p>`

Comment: Very cool! So now, what if I am breaking the alert up by type and with each "Alert", there is also a "type"? So then could it simply be "ppt.Alerts.typeof"? That make sense?

Comment: So just like date, there is also a type. So per my html, I may want to show each date and descr separately for each type. So basically switching on type (hence why I thought of Alerts.type). Thought I could use filter, but not sure that would apply, would it? Like <p ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts | filter:type"> <span>{{date.date}}<span><span>{{date.descr}}<span></p>

Comment: filter would be something like `ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts | filter:{type: type}` will filter the `type` property with `type` variable

Comment: Thanks, but still having issue with it returning all of the alerts using this code: <p ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts | filter:{type: DenialStatement}"> <span>{{date.date}}<span><span>{{date.descr}}<span></p>

Comment: And here are two different types of alerts being returned (one claimreceivednotification and one denialstatement) :

Comment: {
      "id": "181519",
      "date": "2013-06-11T17:12:49",
      "type": "ClaimReceivedNotification",
      "descr": "Your claim submission has been received and is pending review by our claims department.",
      "isRead": false,
      "denialId": "",
      "denialType": "",
      "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "amount": 0
    },

Comment: {
      "id": "181547",
      "date": "2013-06-11T17:44:00",
      "type": "DenialStatement",
      "descr": "A Request for Additional Information and/or Notice of Denial has been issued for your recent claim(s). For more information, please access the Benefits mini-app from the main menu.",
      "isRead": false,
      "denialId": "",
      "denialType": "",
      "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "amount": 0
    },